# How do i get sub properties

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

With VMWare PowerCLi, I am trying to access the properties from a variable but not sure how to get it, My code looks like this so far :

```
    $datastore = Get-Datastore | where {$_.name -like "*geko*"} | select 
    name,remotehost, remotepath | Sort-Object name | ft -AutoSize
    $datastore
```

so the result i get is:

```
Name            RemoteHost        RemotePath      
----            ----------        ----------      
Serv_Geko       {192.168.134.137} /Serv_Geko
```

Question is how do I get the RemotePath in a variable or access it from the above $datastore variable.

I thought I would be able to get it from `$datastore.RemoteHost` but that doesnt seem to work.

I essentially just need to get the IP into a variable so that I can use it lower down in the script.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `$datastore.RemoteHost` ?

Comment: `$NewVariable = $datastore.RemotePath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ft -AutoSize` from your code and then you can access `$datastore.RemoteHost`.

```
PS> $datastore = Get-Datastore | where {$_.name -like "*geko*"} | select 
    name, remotehost, remotepath | Sort-Object name
PS> $datastore.RemoteHost
```

**OR**

Use `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object`.

```
$IPAddress = Get-Datastore | where {$_.name -like "*geko*"} | select-object -ExpandProperty remotehost
```

Now your `$IPAddress`
 contains the IP address.